# How to select/change currency while checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, currency, checkout

I want to give option to my users to select currency at the checkout time. e.g base currency of my website is USD but I want that my users have a facility to pay them in SGD(Singapore Dollar). Is it possible? If possible then deducted amount would be in SGD equivalent to USD.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple currency can be set up in Magento. When you have set up multiple currency properly there will a currency drop-down will come in the header of your site.

Please check the tutorial to know how to set multiple currency

```
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/
```

Comment: What @Suman-php4u wrote is correct But just confirm if payment gateway accepts SGD or not.

Answer (score 0):

You might have noticed the ”Currency Setup” tab in Magento’s Administration under “System->Configuration” menu. There you should select default site currency, and besides that, all currencies you want to support.

After that, you should go to “System->Manage Currency Rates” and set rates for currencies you’ve chosen before. You can use Webservicex to import currency rates from Webservicex service.

And now, after you’re done with initial setup, let’s go further with modifications to make that output shows in the header. First thing you should do is to create a new template file and put it under “YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/currency/currency.phtml”.

__('Your Currency:') ?>
    
        getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            >

You can put in line #10 either $_name or $_code, depending what do you want to show in your currency selector.

Next thing you should do is to tell Magento which template should be used for the selector. You should create “YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml”, or just append the following content if you already have this file in your theme.

And finally, there’s one more thing you’ll need to do to make the template visible on frontend, Open “YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/page/html/header.phtml” (or create new file if there isn’t any)

After this, if you save everything, clear the cache and reload the page, to see the changes and result.

**Note!**

By default, Magento is configured to show default currency selector if there is more than one currency set up.